# Laravel - unable to send email on production

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using ovh cloud server and laravel forge to manage my server, I don't know what happened exactly, I have websites and even wordpress installed , everything was fine and can send email from all websites, nowadays no website send email also no error in the log files, and the email function works fine but no email in inbox or even spam
I've tried changing mail to sendmail, the same issue

please advice me

```
 MAIL_DRIVER=mail
 MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
 MAIL_PORT=465
 MAIL_USERNAME=noreply@****com
 MAIL_PASSWORD=*******
 MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
 MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@*****.com
 MAIL_FROM_NAME=“****”
```

Comment: have you tried `smtp.gmail.com` as the host?

Comment: No but I don’t think it will solve the issue because even wordpress doesn’t have these settings also it is not working

Comment: Tested now and nothing changes

Comment: check your gmail sender may be it's locked

Comment: Ive tested it on local no problem also I chatted with google they said all fine

Comment: I recently had similar problem, deleting the app password and creating new one fixed it for me

Comment: Which app password?

Comment: @IsmailMuhammad if you are using gmail, you should be using app passwords, not the password you are logging in to your account

Answer (score 1):

If your using gmail, delete and create new app password. Here is my config

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=***@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="*****"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: this is not correct, I've changed my password nothing happened!!!